# Invert boolean on click with v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Beginner to JS and VueCLI so I'll try to explain as best as I can. I'm using Express as my back-end.

I'm trying to change the boolean in my array of objects on click. I'm able to accomplish that but when I click on a different list item in my v-for loop it's flipping the boolean in all other indexes of my array. Here's my code:

Express: /routes:

```
        // fake data store
        const tasks = [
           { id: 1, task: 't1', completed: false},
           { id: 2, task: 't2', completed: false},
           { id: 3, task: 't3', completed: false}
        ];

        /**
        * GET handler for /tasks route
        * @returns {Array.<{id: Number, task: String, completed: Boolean}>} array of task objects 
        */
        router.get('/', (req, res) => {
           res.send(tasks);
        });
```

Webapp:

```
        /**
        * GET /tasks
        * @returns Promise => {Array.<{id: Number, task: String, completed: Boolean}>} array of task objects
        */
        export function getTasks() {
           return request('tasks');
        }
```

and now my Vue component:

```
        <template>
        <div id="tasks">
            <h2>Movies to Add</h2>
            <ul class="todo-list">
            <li v-for='task in tasks' :id="task.id" v-on:click="completeMovie($event)" :key='task.id' class="todo-list__li">
                <input class="todo-list__input" type="checkbox" :name='task.task' :id="task.task">
                <div class="todo-list__checkbox">
                <span class="todo-list__checkbox-inner"><i></i></span>
                </div>
                <label :for='task.task'>{{ task.task }}</label>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </template>

        <script>
        import {getTasks} from './../../services/tasks';

        export default {
        name: 'TaskList',
        data: function() {
            return {
            tasks: []
            };
        },
        created: function() {
            getTasks()
            .then(res => this.tasks = res);
        },
        methods: {
            completeMovie: function (event) {
            var taskId = event.currentTarget.id -1;

            getTasks()
                .then((res) => {
                this.tasks = res;
                res[taskId].completed = !res[taskId].completed;
                });
            }
        }
        }
        </script>
```

So when I click on my first list item it changes the Task: t1 to True but if I click on the second list item it changes t1 back to False and t2 to True. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I'm not even sure this is the best way to do this. My main issue is I'm not sure why it's happening.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you fetching all the tasks again when you click one? That's why previous changes are reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably over-complicating this.

All you need is

```html
<li v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" 
    @click="task.completed = !task.completed" 
    class="todo-list__li">
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/xy1q0auL/2/

There's no (obvious) need to re-fetch the tasks every time you click on one. This is why your previous changes are reset; it's because you overwrite all the data with the unmodified values from `getTasks()`.

Comment: Definitely seems as though I've over-complicated it. I did try to do what you suggested and it seems that it's not inverting the boolean, at least not when I'm viewing the data in the vuejs dev console.

Comment: @user3330820 I've added a demo and it works fine for me

Comment: yes it does work and makes perfect sense that it would. Something else must be going on for me? When I console log tasks in your example I get the array of objects, however when I do so in my instance I get an HTMLDivElement. See screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/tqelH3U.png I'm wondering if that has to do with my issue?

Comment: I had an ID of "tasks" in my html which was causing issues. Also had an issue with the event listener running twice because the click function was on the LI but was also being triggered by the label. Cleaned it up and all is working. One last thing in case anyone else comes by this. The data in my array wasn't update in realtime in the vuejs dev console, which I did not realize was normal. When I switch components and come back to the component I was working on I could then see the boolean was inverted. Thanks @Phil!

Answer (score 0):

When completeMovie() is called, you send an HTTP request to your server that is gonna send you back unaltered task list. I don't understand clearly what's you're trying to achieve but your callback in the promise has no sens. In the callback you reaffect the "tasks" list in your vue :

[image]

In this case, here is the event timeline you have to do :

- When client page is loaded, Vue Initialized, the vue component calls your webservice to get the task list then print it.
- Then when I click on a task, you have to make a another HTTP call to your webservice (on another route), that will update the task list and will return it.
- Then in the call of your vue component you reaffect the new task list.

Answer (score 0):

You can make its simply:

```
 <li v-for='task in tasks' :id="task.id" v-on:click="completeMovie(task.id)" :key='task.id' class="todo-list__li">
            <input class="todo-list__input" type="checkbox" :name='task.task' :id="task.task">
            <div class="todo-list__checkbox">
            <span class="todo-list__checkbox-inner"><i></i></span>
            </div>
            <label :for='task.task'>{{ task.task }}</label>
        </li>
```

Ans for the method

```
completeMovie: function ($taskId) {
        this.tasks[$taskId].completed = !this.tasks[$taskId].completed;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `tasks` is an array so each element is accessed by index, not `task.id`

Comment: Yes, sorry the v-for line should be <li v-for="(task, key) in tasks" v-on:click="completeMovie(key)"  class="todo-list__li">